# Find a String and return the words after it

Tags: java

I have this method which receive as parameters pdfText(which is a String containing text from a pdf file after parsing) and fileName which is the file where i want to write that text

But now I need to find the word "Keywords" in this text and extract only the words after it,which are in the same line(until the newline character).

For example I have one text which contains somewhere the following line

> Title:Something.
>
> **"Keywords : Computers, Robots, Course"**
>
> Tags:tag1,tag2,tag3.

And the result should be the following list **["Computers","Robots", "Course"].**

***Solved Question***

So I've searched how to solve my question..here is a solution,not very smart but it works:

```
            //index of first appearence of the word 
            int index = pdfText.indexOf("Keywords");

            //string from that to the end
            String subStr = pdfText.substring(index);


            //index of first appearence of the new line in the new string
            int index1 = subStr.indexOf("\n");


            //the string we need
            String theString = subStr.substring(9,index1); 

            System.out.println(theString);

            //write in the file..use true as parameter for appending text,not overwrite it
            FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
            pw.write(theString);

            pw.close();
```

Comment: Please show some attempt! Just because you posted code does not mean you made any effort to solve your problem.

Comment: You may manage to get an A on this assignment by having others do your work, but you'll get an F on the final.

Comment: Hint: Research `String#split()` `String#startsWith()`

Comment: (The above code you posted is obviously just random junk, unrelated to the assignment.)  (And if you don't understand that you should practice saying "Will you have fries with that?")

Comment: thanks @KevinBowersox .I didn't knew from where to start with..

Comment: @HotLicks ..that was pretty funny...But the application is a little bit more complex,not just the code i've posted... I am new to java,I know this is'n an excuse..I work on web programming and I find this pretty diffent,...I didn't ask ask for a complete code,just for hits...:)

Comment: *hints..sorry for the spelling errors

Comment: OK, hint:  Read the documentation for String.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this question is too situation specific. Regardless :)

**Writing to file**

```
String pdfText = "pdfText";
String fileLocation = "fileLocation";
Writer writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(fileLocation), "utf-8"));
    writer.write(pdfText);     // String you want to write (i.e. pdfText)
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

It's always a good idea to specify the encoding type. ("utf-8"). It might not matter for your assignment though. You might also need to **append to the file**, and not re-write it completely, in which case, you should use a different constructor for the FileOutputStream, `new FileOutputStream(getFileLocation(), true)` . As for the many try/catch blocks, don't follow my example. It's how I manage to close my resource, as eclipse recommends haha.

**Parsing the String**
If you have a line such as `"Keywords : Computers, Robots, Course"`,

```
String str = "Keywords : Computers, Robots, Course";
String[] array = str.substring(indexOf(':') + 1).split(",");
//this array = ["Computers", "Robots", "Course"]
```

Now you have an array which you can loop through and write/print out however you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `regex` to extract the words after the word "Keyword:" like this :

```
String regex = ".*Keywords\\s*:(.*)\\n.*";

String extractedLine = yourText.replaceAll( regex, "$1" );

System.out.println( extractedLine );
```